# JAVa IO Restriction on Windows / UnIX Server causing application Unknown Issue

Tags: java, file, unix, io, constraints

I am facing a very strange issue in java(J2EE App.). I have an Application that reads data from  customer configuration Files placed in a location on local machine/ server , reads it via Java API and Displays it on the UI of the Tool. later, Through UI, the data can be Changed and is written back to the file by tool via Java API.

The problem is that the tool fails to read information (reads half of the file) and causes data loss on the UI. But the Issue is not Consistent.  It happens About 1 in 20 times only. Rest it always reads well.

I am not able to reproduce the issue on my WINDOwS machine. But is was seen in the Production Server (ON UNIX Environment).

Please Suggest what I need to check. Are there any Permission related Issues in UNIX.

Can my tool have a Bug in it? or is it environment problem that the tool suffers from.

Should I try

```
try {

// my code 

} catch(Throwable t) {

   t.printStackTrace();  

}
```

To debug if it's an issue in Environment?

Answer (score 1):

Windows tends to lock files so you are less likely to read it while it is being written to.  Linux takes the view you know what you are doing and doesn't lock by default.  This means you can see files before you have finished.  This is a common problem with files as they are not designed as a messaging protocol and so you have to come up with something heuristic to handle this deficiency.  A better approach is to not use files for communication between processes or you have to be very aware of it's limitations.

Comment: Thanks Peter Lawrey, But do you think it can be a Bug as well , this is one thing that is haunting (My Application is known to be a haunted application , because of this reason). I am not able to reproduce it again. Can we conclude that it is environment specific if we cannot reproduce anymore.??

Comment: There is different ways that Windows and Linux access programs.  For this reason I use Linux for development and test if the target system is Linux.  In fact I suggest you use Centos for example, rather than unubtu if that is what you plan to use.